# How to use state on one element of map on typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state, styled-components

I want to use `onClick` on one element of my map and set "favorite" for it. Basically, I'm trying to change the SVG of a Icon to the filled version, but with the map, all of items are changing too.

I already try to pass this to `onClick`, but doesn't work.

My code:

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Slider from "react-slick";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick.css";
import "slick-carousel/slick/slick-theme.css";
import { ForwardArrow } from "../../../assets/images/ForwardArrow";
import { BackArrow } from "../../../assets/images/BackArrow";
import * as S from "./styled";
import { IconFavoriteOffer } from "../../../assets/images/IconFavoriteOffer";
import { Rating } from "../../../assets/images/Rating";
import { TruckFill } from "../../../assets/images/TruckFill";
import { OpenBox } from "../../../assets/images/OpenBox";
import { IconCartWht } from "../../../assets/images/IconCartWht";
import axios from "axios";
import { off } from "process";
import SwitcherFavorite from "../SwitcherFavorite";


export default function Carousel() {
  const [offers, setOffers] = useState<any[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://localhost:5000/offers").then((response) => {
      setOffers(response.data);
    });
  }, []);

  const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState(true);

  const toggleFavorite = () => {
    setFavorite((favorite) => !favorite);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Slider {...settings}>
        {offers.map((offer, index) => {
          return (
            <S.Offer key={index}>
              <>
                <S.OfferCard>
                  <S.OfferCardTop>
                    <S.OfferContentTop>
                      <S.OfferFavorite>
                        <S.OfferFavoriteButton onClick={toggleFavorite}> // Want to get this element of mapping
                          <SwitcherFavorite favorite={favorite} />
                        </S.OfferFavoriteButton>
                      </S.OfferFavorite>
                      <S.OfferStars>
                        <Rating />
                      </S.OfferStars>
                    </S.OfferContentTop>
                  </S.OfferCardTop>
                </S.OfferCard>
              </>
            </S.Offer>
          );
        })}
      </Slider>
    </>
  );
}
```

So, how can I do it?

Comment: When clicking one of them you need to store the specific one that was clicked in state, not just toggle a flag. Does each `offer` in the array have something like a unique ID value you can use to distinguish them? If not you could just store the index of the one clicked, though that is a bad method since it can cause bugs when the list changes.

Comment: @ChristianMeneghetti nice :) thanks a lot for letting me know. If this answer solved your problem please mark it as an official answer or leave an upvote if it doesn't bother you :)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a single `boolean` flag with your current `[favorite, setFavorite] = useState(false)` for all the offers, which wouldn't work, you can store the list of `offer` IDs in an array. In this way you can also have multiple favourited offers.

Assuming your `offer` item has a unique `id` property or similar:

```js
// This will store an array of IDs of faved offers
const [favorite, setFavorite] = useState([]);
const toggleFavorite = (id) => {
  setFavorite((previousFav) => {
    if (previousFav.includes(id)) {
      // remove the id from the list
      // if it already existed
      return previousFav.filter(favedId => favedId !== id);
    }

    // add the id to the list
    // if it has not been here yet
    return [...previousFav, id]);
  }
};
```

And then in your JSX:

```
/* ... */
<S.OfferFavoriteButton onClick={() => toggleFavorite(offer.id) }>
  <SwitcherFavorite favorite={favorite.includes(offer.id)} />
  // Similar to your original boolean flag to switch icons
</S.OfferFavoriteButton>
/* ... */
```